# python 3.6, sqlite OperationalError: near "to": syntax error

Tags: python, sqlite

I have real stressful problem. This is my code.

```
match_columns_allword = [hgggg,wtf,gg,lmao,hahah,ok,game,miss,click,zo,guys,please,ima,celebrity,get,me,out,of,here,someone,has,to,lose,mmr,which,you,used,glyph,damn,easy,fuck,u,all,ez,pieces,shit,d,fuckkkkkkkkk,uuu,am,pickers,izi,sniper,yeah,go,on,meeeee,wp,sec,how,like,that,ld,and,aa,wala,bb,cemen,ah,ajg,ggwp,commend,ty,orge,swap,tips,isit,agin,awwoo,are,bored,stop,it,nice,tp,under,tower,ff,bear,man,broken,fucking,hero,im,sorry,cavern,x,its,fine,come,fight,pls,lol,elp,we,cannot,end,oh,dear,goddamn,notlikethis,dusts,blind,team,mooooo,thanks,missed,jesus,finally,my,god,christ,what,a,haha,asdasdasd,no]
conn = sqlite3.connect('chat.db')
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute("CREATE TABLE all_word_counts (match_id,"+str(",".join(match_columns_allword))+")")
```

But after this, an error occurred.

```
OperationalError: near "to": syntax error
```

I've tried to find a way, but all failed. especially, using parametrized SQL made the same result.

```
table_var = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS match_columns_allword (?{1})"
table_var = table_var.format(",".join(match_columns_allword), ",?"* (len(match_columns_allword)))
cur.execute(table_var, [match_columns_allword])
OperationalError: near "to": syntax error
```

I don't know what happened, and what is a problem because these 2 codes always work as expected. Please somebody help me.....

Comment: Have you tried putting `"` around the words in your list? `["hgggg","wtf","gg","lmao","hahah"` etc.

Comment: Yes. actually each word of the list is covered by single quote. and now I made another list and put the " each of them, but it didn't work.

Comment: oh, after comment, I tried another way. 
'cur.execute('''CREATE TABLE match_columns_allword ("match_id","'''+str('''","'''.join(match_columns_allword))+'''")''')'
this make each word have "" and finally it works! I really appriciate it!

Comment: Oh, your code probably has more problems than just that, but it definitely helps.

Answer (score 0):

I am truly grateful to Mast. My problem was solved. But I'm not familiar with comment system, so my code in comment looks strange. here is a new one.

```
cur.execute('''CREATE TABLE match_columns_allword ("match_id","'''+str('''","'''.join(match_columns_allword))+'''")''')
```

This is my first question at stack overflow, and I really thank you.